# OpenStack SDK GetObjectSaveToFile Headers

Tags: c#, .net, openstack, rackspace, rackspace-cloudfiles

I am trying to download a file using the openstack sdk from rackspace files.  If the file already exists I want to use the range header to continue writing where it left off.  According to their [documentation](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/GET_getobjectdata_v1__account___container___object__objectServicesOperations_d1e000.html) this can be accomplished.  The [openstack sdk documentation](http://openstacknetsdk.org/docs/html/M_net_openstack_Providers_Rackspace_CloudFilesProvider_GetObjectSaveToFile.htm) says I can set the range header.  Here is my code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\path\to\file.zip"))
        {
            long iExistLen = 0;
            System.IO.FileInfo fINfo =
              new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\path\to\file.zip");
            iExistLen = fINfo.Length;

            headers.Add("Range", "bytes="+iExistLen+"-");
        }

        CloudIdentity cloudIdentity = new CloudIdentity()
        {
            APIKey = apikey,
            Username = username
        };

        CloudFilesProvider cloudFilesProvider = new CloudFilesProvider(cloudIdentity);
        cloudFilesProvider.GetObjectSaveToFile(containerName, @"C:\path\to\", fileName, "file.zip", 65536, headers);
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
The 'Range' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some common headers are considered restricted and are either exposed directly by the API (such as Content-Type) or protected by the system and cannot be changed. `Range` is one of that headers.
Full list is:

```
Accept
Connection
Content-Length
Content-Type
Date
Expect
Host
If-Modified-Since
Range
Referer
Transfer-Encoding
User-Agent
Proxy-Connection
```

Comment: So how would you set the range header using the sdk?

Comment: Try to use WebClient like: WebClient headers = new WebClient();
headers.Headers.Add("Range", "something"); I mean not the Dictionary, because in GetObjectSaveToFile on it's place is the collection of custom HTTP headers.

Comment: So then there is no way to set the range header within the SDK?